# Implementing AppleID login as a webview in a native app

Tags: ios, swift, webview, apple-id

Is is possible for a native iOS app to have AppleID signup implemented as a webview? Or will it result in rejection during the review process?

If it is possible, have you come across such apps that are there in the AppStore?

I found the information about AppleJS and WKWebView solution here (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/119198) but it seems it's only related to the web, while my question relates exclusively to native mobile solution.

Thanks in advance for any tips

Comment: Why would you want to use a web view in a native app when there is a much simpler native implementation that will give a better user experience?  It seems likely that Apple would reject a web base Sign In with Apple.

Comment: The forum thread you linked says "AppleJS API is fully compatible with the FaceID/TouchID login when executed through WKWebView or Safari browser." Does that answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

It's not recommended for native iOS app to have AppleID signup implemented as a webview. Apple may Reject your app.

Use Authentication Services for Apple Platforms. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices